# Getting date/time from DatePicker in swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uidatepicker

I have created a separate class for Date Picker.

```
import UIKit

protocol MYDatePickerViewControllerDelegate {
    func didFinishSelectingDate(selectedDate:NSDate)
}

class MYDatePickerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!

    var datePickerDelegate : MYDatePickerViewControllerDelegate?
    var customTransitioningDelegate: MYFadeInFadeOutTransitioning? = MYFadeInFadeOutTransitioning()

    init(){
        super.init(nibName: "MyDatePickerViewController", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())

        transitioningDelegate = customTransitioningDelegate
        modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
    }
    convenience init(withSelectedDate date: NSDate) {
        self.init()

    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    deinit {
        customTransitioningDelegate = nil
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViewControllerUI()
    }

    func setupViewControllerUI() {
        containerView.tag = kContainerViewTag

    }

    @IBAction func doneButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        datePickerDelegate?.didFinishSelectingDate(self.datePicker.date)
        print(self.datePicker.date)
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func cancelButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Which I am presenting from a different viewController as

```
let timePickerViewController = MYDatePickerViewController()
presentViewController(timePickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

it does present from bottom of screen as follows

[image]

Now I am trying to get the selected date when user tap the done button on datePicker. For that i am trying to create a delegate and get selecetd date from there. but could not.
I have implemneted the delegate of MYDatePickerViewController into my other ViewController as

in my viewDidLoad

```
let datePicker = YASDatePickerViewController()
    datePicker.datePickerDelegate = self
```

and then

```
func didFinishSelectingDate(selectedDate: NSDate) {
    print(selectedDate)
}
```

But I am not getting the date, please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this While presenting from a different viewController as:

```
let timePickerViewController = MYDatePickerViewController()
timePickerViewController.datePickerDelegate = self
presentViewController(timePickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And in conform viewController to your protocol:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MYDatePickerViewControllerDelegate {
```

Rest looks fine!

Comment: I was missing this line timePickerViewController.datePickerDelegate = self
   Thank you so much.